# SQL: Count the entities travelling with the between dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is what my table looks like:

| carid | date of departure | date of arrival |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12-03-2022 | 16-03-2022 |
| 2 | 15-03-2022 | 18-03-2022 |
| 3 | 16-03-2022 | 19-03-2022 |
| 4 | 20-03-2022 | 23-03-2022 |

And I need the output to be like:

| Date | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 12-03-2022 | 1 |
| 13-03-2022 | 1 |
| 14-03-2022 | 1 |
| 15-03-2022 | 2 |
| 16-03-2022 | 3 |
| 17-03-2022 | 2 |

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Can you provide the select you are executing?

Comment: @ericmp Right now just counting the dates per day but thats not helping with the days between them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data table name is TRAVELS, create a new table RESULTS with these fields:

```
xdate as date, primary key
n as integer
```

Now, try something like this code:

```
docmd.runsql "delete from RESULTS"
dim TRAVELS as recordset
dim RESULTS as recordset
set TRAVELS= currentdb.openrecordset("TRAVELS" , dbopenforwardonly , dbreadonly)
set RESULTS= currentdb.openrecordset("RESULTS")
RESULTS.index= "primarykey"
dim xdate as date
do while not TRAVELS.eof
    xdate= TRAVELS!date_of_departure
    do while xdate <= TRAVELS!date_of_arrival
        RESULTS.seek "=" , xdate
        if RESULTS.nomatch then
            RESULTS.addnew
            RESULTS!xdate= xdate
            RESULTS!n= 1
            RESULTS.update
        else
            RESULTS.edit
            RESULTS!n= RESULTS!n + 1
            RESULTS.update
        end if
        xdate= dateadd("d" , 1 , xdate)
    loop
    TRAVELS.movenext
loop
TRAVELS.close
set TRAVELS= nothing
RESULTS.close
set RESULTS= nothing
```